# ¿porque tm cambia de valor al usar asctime?

Tags: c++

tengo el siguiente código en c++ que calcula la diferencia de tiempo entre 2 fechas

```
int diferencia_entre_fechas(std::string fecha1, std::string fecha2)
{
    //Retorna en segundos la diferencia entre dos fechas dadas
    tm fecha_menor, fecha_mayor;
    time_t epoca1, epoca2;

    strptime(fecha1.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &fecha_menor);
    strptime(fecha2.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &fecha_mayor);

    //Esto hace lo mismo que las 2 lineas de arriba
    //std::istringstream fmenor(fecha1);
    //std::istringstream fmayor(fecha2);
    //fmenor >> std::get_time(&fecha_menor, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    //fmayor >> std::get_time(&fecha_mayor, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    epoca1 = mktime(&fecha_menor);
    epoca2 = mktime(&fecha_mayor);

    //std::cout << fecha_menor.tm_mday << "-" << fecha_menor.tm_mon << "-" << fecha_menor.tm_year << " " <<fecha_menor.tm_hour << ":" << fecha_menor.tm_min << ":" << fecha_menor.tm_sec << "\n";
    //std::cout << fecha_mayor.tm_mday << "-" << fecha_mayor.tm_mon << "-" << fecha_mayor.tm_year << " " <<fecha_mayor.tm_hour << ":" << fecha_mayor.tm_min << ":" << fecha_mayor.tm_sec << "\n";

    //std::cout << "tm 1: " << asctime(&fecha_menor) << "\n";
    //std::cout << "tm 2: " << asctime(&fecha_mayor) << "\n";

    //std::cout << "diferencia: " << difftime(epoca2, epoca1) << "\n";

    return difftime(epoca2, epoca1);
}
```

Da el resultado correcto hasta que es llamada desde la función actualizar_tiempo.

```
Glib::signal_timeout().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Ventana::actualizar_tiempo), 1000);

bool Ventana::actualizar_tiempo()
{
    if(tiempo < 0)
        controlador->entrar_y_salir();
}

//Este es otro archivo
void Controlar::entrar_y_salir()
{
    //Funcion para iniciar y detener el contador de tiempo
    std::string hora_entrada = "2019-01-18 11:32:00";
    std::string hora_salida = "2019-01-18 11:32:04";
    int tiempo = diferencia_entre_fechas(hora_entrada, hora_salida);
    ....
}
```

lo que pasa es que el resultado es negativo cuando siempre debería ser positivo. (tiempo = -3596)

pero cuando intento ver el valor de las variable tm fecha_menor, fecha_mayor con asctime el problema se arregla (tiempo = 4) ¿por que ocurre esto?

tambien se arregla si imprimo `std::cout << "diferencia: " << difftime(epoca2, epoca1) << "\n";` antes del return.

fecha_menor.tm_hour contiene 12 no 11 como debería según el ejemplo.

fecha_mayor.tm_hour contiene 11 esta esta bien.

Comment: Pues parece [que funciona bien](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o1SajTn0n8IYv2Mb).

Comment: Si, el problema solo ocurre cuando se llama desde Glib::signal_timeout() y si se descomenta la linea `std::cout << "diferencia: " << difftime(epoca2, epoca1) << "\n";` funciona también, no puedo entender porque al imprimirlo corrige el problema.

Comment: ¿No estarás usando herramientas del siglo pasado, tipo `dev-cpp` o similares, verdad?

Comment: Si no es así todo apunta a que se está pisando memoria. Posiblemente tengas algún puntero que interfiere en los resultados y el hecho de poner esas líneas que comentas hacen que el compilador estructure el código de forma diferente y por eso deja de fallar

Comment: @eferion no uso dev-cpp, utilizo kate para escribir el código y un makefile para compilar con g++ ¿en que afectaría eso?, ¿como detecto el puntero que falla? al compilar no da ningún mensaje de erro o advertencia.

Comment: No suele ser obvio... comprueba todos los punteros que use tu programa, asegúrate que se inicializan todos correctamente y que no se queda alguno apuntando a un objeto borrado. Un primer paso puede ser cambiar los punteros *crudos* (`int*`) por punteros inteligentes (`std::shared_ptr<int>` y `std::unique_ptr<int>`)

Comment: @Trauma probé el mismo código que corres en https://wandbox.org/permlink/o1SajTn0n8IYv2Mb usando mi compilador y me da resultados erroneos:
carlos@equipo-2:~/Escritorio$ g++ ejemplo.c++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic  
carlos@equipo-2:~/Escritorio$ ./a.out  
0  
3601  
3602  
3603  
3604  
3605  
3606  
3607  
3608  
3609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenemos que leer la *letra pequeña* de la documentación de `strptime( )` para descubrir tu problema (tomado de la página del manual):

> #### OBSERVACIONES
>
> En  principio,  esta  función  no  inicializa  la  estructura  `tm`  sino  que  simplemente  almacena los valores especificados. Esto quiere decir que la estructura `tm` debe ser inicializada antes de la llamada. Los detalles pueden  diferir  ligeramente  entre  diferentes  sistemas  Unix. La implementación de libc de GNU no modifica aquellos campos que  no  son especificados  explícitamente,  salvo  los  campos  `tm_wday`  y  `tm_yday`   que  son recalculados si cualquiera de los elementos año, mes o día son alterados.

Pues ya hemos descubierto tu problema: **no está inicializando** tus `struct tm`. Es fácil de solucionar:

```
int diferencia_entre_fechas( const std::string &fecha1, const std::string &fecha2 ) {
  tm fecha_menor, fecha_mayor;
  time_t epoca1, epoca2;

  memset( &fecha_menor, 0, sizeof( fecha_menor ) ); // <- Esto
  memset( &fecha_mayor, 0, sizeof( fecha_mayor ) ); // <- y esto

  strptime( fecha1.c_str( ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &fecha_menor );
  strptime( fecha2.c_str( ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &fecha_mayor );

  epoca1 = mktime( &fecha_menor );
  epoca2 = mktime( &fecha_mayor );

  return difftime( epoca2, epoca1 );
}
```

Simplemente, las rellenamos con `0` **antes** de pasarlas a la función `strptime( )`.